# How to differentiate between static and instance methods using YourKit Java Profiler?

Tags: java, profiler, yourkit

I'm currently using YourKit Java Profiler to gather information about the total number of invoked methods during profiling. However, I'm facing difficulty in distinguishing between static methods and instance methods.

When I perform [CPU profiling (tracing)](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/tracing.jsp), I obtain a list of methods, but there seems to be no apparent way to identify whether a method is static or instance-based. For instance, here are two sample entries from the method list:

- Instance `java.lang.String.charAt(int) String.java`
- Static `java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(byte[], byte, int, String, int) String.java`

Both methods appear identical and lack any indication of their type (static or instance). I have extensively searched through the official documentation provided by YourKit, but have been unable to find any relevant information on this matter.

Is it possible to differentiate between static and instance methods during profiling using YourKit? If so, what approach or feature should I utilize to achieve this? I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance regarding this issue.

Comment: By the way: both methods you list are instance methods - `"abca".lastIndexOf('a')` is 3. Perhaps base your checks on something like "String.format()" which is static.